# TEXTJOIN() on an array incorrectly returns a blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

**TL;DR:** `TEXTJOIN()` on an array returns a blank - can't use VBA to solve the issue in an alternative way.

I've created several sheets with heavy dependence on Array functions due to limitations disallowing me from creating a macro-enabled workbook.

So far, this is working out quite alright, but I am running into a problem with [`TEXTJOIN()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c).

Basically, it's the following formula:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);TRUE;IF(A3:A100="test";B3:B100;""))}
```

returning a blank (not an error). Using the 'Evaluate Formula' tool shows that the penultimate step generates the right array (with two non null string values in it). However, the next step is empty. See the screenshot:

[image: Evaluate Formula for the Textjoin function]

Edit: clearer picture:

[image: Evaluate Formula for Textjoin, cell remains empty]

This been puzzling me for quite some time now, so any help or alternative solutions that do not rely on VBA would be much appreciated!

Comment: That is very strange. (I don't have Excel 2016 so I'm using a poly-fill UDF which works fine with your formula.) What happens if you change the `CHAR(10)` to something else like `"#"`?

Comment: the only error i can see is the misplaced { it should be {=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);TRUE;IF(A3:A100="test";B3:B100;""))} Your formula works fine for me in 2016

Comment: I tried with different delimiter, the problem is still the same. @PeterH: Can you help me see what I'm missing? What exactly is the difference between our formula's?

Comment: @hooge I am at a loss, I copied your EXACT formula and it works

Comment: Could you have formatted the text to white?

Comment: @ScottCraner: considered that and already tried changing the font to no avail. Also, the last step of the Evaluate Formula is also empty, it really does seem empty.

Comment: @ScottCraner Good one! Unfortunately, hooge has said that the next Evaluate Formula step results in a blank.

Comment: Try restarting Excel, creating a new blank workbook, and then copy-pasting the formula from the question. (And add the data, of course.)

Comment: I wonder if there's a limit on the length of the array? You've said that you've tried one cell but have you tried something else less than 500 cells? Do two cells work?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your formula is working properly but do not have Excel 2016 to verify my suspicions.  What I think is happening is you are concatenating 100 carriage returns.  This will result in output that will be somewhere in excess of 1000 pixels high but Excel will only permit a row height of 407 pixels so the visible text portion of the output is being hidden from view.

You can confirm my suspicions with the following test: copy the output cell (Summary!C21) and paste it into a blank Notepad session.  If the cell contains data, you will be able to see it in Notepad.  Alternatively, you might convert the formula to its value using [F2] then [F9] and then trying to scroll up and down the output.

If my suspicion is correct, I am afraid you will need to research another method of displaying the data you require - probably by using additional formulas to filter out the data you wish to display.

Answer (score 0):

As to "another method of displaying the data you require"... While it is so definitely true that Excel limits row heights to 407 points and your data would seem to very much exceed that causing the majority of it to be cut off from view by the row height limit, Excel does NOT limit its display past that kind of limit.

This might make what I mean clearer:  if you `Merge` several rows' cells, you can display much more than 407 points. So for 1,000 points, merge three rows' cells and make the row heights of the three rows whatever (allowed) heights you like so long as they total more than 1,000 points and see if that displays all your content. If not, add height to the contraption. If more than needed, take some away.

I have a 24" "class" monitor which probably means (American marketing lies...) a height nowhere near that, but looking at it, let's say 15 real inches tall (how wide and what diagonal measurement... AND how those a verminously then increased to claim some "inch class" size isn't important here... just the height is). 407 points is about 5½" high, so two such cells should display. But the don't. Not with all the happy horsesh*t Excel fills the window with. You may experience the same problem.

If so, reduce the magnification to as low as needed to display the cells. Or, if a "single take" view isn't important to your use, and the newly added (in 2021, not 2018!) "smooth scrolling" will do, leave it alone, or find a happy mix of some reduction and some smooth scrolling.

Seems odd, but it really works. Generally, except for pages built solely for viewing what is essentially a report or printing such, `Merged` cells are frowned upon. One should note, the essence here is "for anything that might want to make halfway sophisticated use of what is on the screen" with dashboard and other reports not being so. Rather, it refers to using formulas to collect and groom row upon row of data. If that is not your need for this material, the above solution might suit you. If you also need the computer to process the information created by this approach, then the above display idea probably won't suit your needs as it would make formulas very hard in many cases.